# Fingerprint Scanner on T480s?

Tags: kde, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

Has anyone gotten the fingerprint scanner working on the Thinkpad T480s?

I installed fingerprint-gui, but it just says "No Device Found."

I'm on KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04 base) with all the latest updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fingerprint drivers were not released for linux. There are some efforts being made in the commnunity to reverse engineer the drivers. You can find the latest progress here: https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui`

`sudo apt install fingerprint-gui`

`fingerprint-gui -d`

If you get any errors copy and paste in reply.

Comment: As I said in my post, I already installed `fingerprint-gui`, and when I open it up, it doesn't give me any fingerprint scanners to choose from, just says "No Devices found!"

Comment: Sorry I missed that. In that case you need to install the driver for the finger print scanner. The driver is called thinkfinger you can download it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/thinkfinger/files/

Comment: But you will have to manually compile and install the driver. You can find more info on compiling here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: Last update to that software was in 2013? Are you sure it works with T480s?